# Using lightning component in custom site

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created a lightning component. I want to use that component in site and access that component through site url.

For example, we can access vf page externally without authentication by adding that vf page in sites.

Comment: You want to embed your lightning component into vf page then , you can add that vf page in sites.

Comment: I have done this but I found some issues there. 
1) When I see lightning component in vf page, it affecting the slds which I have given in component.
2) I have created one lightning component and it has

<aura:attribute name="insertRecord" type="Account" />. 
If I give "List" instead of "Account" in type, it showing in site. Otherwise only blank page.

Comment: Is there any other way to create site for lightning component without using vf page?

Comment: Still its not supported in site page

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm) to put Lightning components on a non-Salesforce site without visualforce.

The `ltng:allowGuestAccess` interface is used to make the app public. The full documentation is on the [Salesforce dev site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_public_apps.htm). Be sure to read the security warnings first.